# Invalid value used as weak map key when using iron-list

Tags: angular, polymer

I'm trying to use Angular 2 with Polymer and when I tried using an `iron-list` inside of my component's HTML templates with a static array of strings as a test and I got this huge stack trace. [image]

In my component, I'm using Vaadin's Elements to be able to use Polymer elements inside Angular 2

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {PolymerElement} from '@vaadin/angular2-polymer'
import {CoursesService} from '../services/courses.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'courses',
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/courses.component.html',
    directives: [PolymerElement('iron-list'), PolymerElement('iron-ajax')], // Originally tried iron-ajax but didn't pan out so well
    providers: [CoursesService]
})
export class CoursesComponent implements OnInit {
    coursesData;

    constructor(coursesService: CoursesService) {
        this.coursesData = coursesService.getCourses();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

I return an array of strings in this service which I'm trying to display but throws the error

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CoursesService {

    constructor() { }

    getCourses() : string[] {
        return ["Course 1", "Course 2", "Course 3"]
    }
}
```

and then the template for the component, I try to use the same variable as the one in the component TypeScript.

```
<iron-list items="{{coursesData}}" as="item">
    <template>[[item]]</template>
</iron-list>
```